# Rxjs - Consume API output and re-query when cache is empty

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm trying to implement a version of [this intro to RxJS](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/guidelines/introduction/index.html) ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/staltz/8jFJH/48/)) that instead of picking a random object from a returned API array, it consumes a backthrottled stream of  objects from the returned API array.

Here's a portion of the code that produces a controlled `Observable` from the API response (full fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ctk2bhah/2/)):

```
var responseStream = requestStream.flatMap(function (requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch(requestUrl));
}).flatMap(function(response) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(response.json());
}).flatMap(function(json) {
    return Rx.Observable.from(json);
}).controlled();
```

I just dump each emitted user in `console.log`, and use a `click` event stream to trigger the `request()` call in the controlled Observable:

```
responseStream.subscribe(function(user) {
  console.log(user);
});

refreshClickStream.subscribe(function (res) {
    responseStream.request(1);
});
```

There's about 50 user objects returned from the GitHub API, and I'd like to backthrottle-consume them one per click (as seen above). *However*, after I'm fresh out of user objects I'd like to send in another call to `requestStream` to fetch another API call, replenish the `responseStream` and continue providing user objects to `console.log` upon each click. What would be the RxJS-friendly way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it similarly to the article example with `combineLatest()` although I wonder if there's an easier way than mine.

I'm making request for only 3 items. Working with 3 items is hardcoded so you'll want to modify this. I was thinking about making it universal but that would require using `Subject` and made it much more complicated so I stayed with this simple example.

Also, I'm using `concatMap()` to trigger fetching more data. However, just clicking the link triggers just the `combineLatest()` which emits another item from the array.

See live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/h3bwwjaz/12/

```
var refreshButton = document.querySelector('#main');
var refreshClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(refreshButton, 'click')
  .startWith(0)
  .scan(function(acc, val, index) {
    return index;
  });

var usersStream = refreshClickStream
  .filter(function(index) {
    return index % 3 === 0;
  })
  .concatMap(function() {
    var randomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    var url = 'https://api.github.com/users?since=' + randomOffset + '&per_page=3';
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(fetch(url))
      .flatMap(function(response) {
        return Rx.Observable.fromPromise(response.json());
      });
  })
  .combineLatest(refreshClickStream, function(responseArray, index) {
    return responseArray[index % 3];
  })
  .distinct();

usersStream.subscribe(function(user) {
  console.log(user);
});
```

I use `refreshClickStream` twice:

- to emit next item in the array in `combineLatest()`
- to check whether this is the end of the array and we need to make another request (that's the `filter()` operator).

At the end [`distinct()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinct.md) is required because when you click `index % 3 === 0` time triggers in fact two emission. First is the one from downloading the data and the second one is directly in `combineLatest()` that we want to ignore because we don't want to iterate the same data again. Thanks to `distinct()` it's ignored and only the new values is passed.

I was trying to figure out a method without using `distinct()` but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty clever. I was thinking there wouldn't be a solution without using `Subject`s but you did it! In a way, we're building the array iterator within the stream and resetting it. That's pretty cool.

You mentioned having to use `Subject`s to make it universal - is it because we'd  have to look forward in the array to send a `onNext` to our Subject and trigger another API pull?

Comment: @MaxAlcala I wanted to use `Subject` to be able to feed it into `filter()` which has be to used before even knowing how many items are in the array.