# rxJS observable to repeat call every time condition is met in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'd basically like to implement an observable pool consumer.

So, a service makes an http call to retrieve a number of results and then a component is consuming those results one by one.
When the service detects that is running out of results it will make a call again to the server for a number of new results.

I started trying to make single http calls and subscribe and unsubscribe every time, but it seems quite messy and confusing.

I'd like something like this:

```
this.http
  .post(API, postData)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .subscribe(data => this.saveData(data))
  .repeat(when_certain_condition)
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I read about repeat but it seems like you need to provide the value to be repeated, so it doesn´t seem like the way to go.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: This is very dependent on what your response looks like and how exactly you consume the items. It seems like a very similar question is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40348748/rxjs-consume-api-output-and-re-query-when-cache-is-empty/40359622#40359622

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the very same situation, and I solved with the following approach.

```
this.http
  .post(API, postData)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .delay(2000)
  .flatMap(data => {
    this.saveData(data);
    if (when_certain_condition) {
      return Observable.throw('retry');
    } else {
      return Observable.of(data);
    }
  }).retry().subscribe();
```

Explanation:

1. You need to use a `flatMap()` to transform the items emitted by an Observable into Observables
2. You need to use `Observable.throw()` to force an error, in this way the `retry()` will be invoked
3. I used a `delay(2000)`, in this way I wait 2 seconds before retrying another call

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if `doWhile` is not available, then emulate it with `retry`:

```
this.http
  .post(API, postData)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .do(data => {
       this.saveData(data);
       if(data.length > 0){
           throw new Error();
       }
   })
  .retry()
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: The `doWhile()` operator is no longer implemented. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed

Comment: Man... I was getting crazy trying to find it... :(

Comment: retry doesn´t seem to do what I want, it responds to errors
I managed to get what I wanted but not with a single observable, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891630/rxjs-observable-not-reaching-subscribe/41892103#41892103